# Server-client search architecture with PIT in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use search_after and PIT to provide consistent search results. The [guide](https://www.elastic.co/kr/blog/get-a-consistent-view-of-your-data-over-time-with-the-elasticsearch-point-in-time-reader) documentation suggests that PITs should be generated in the background and utilized after each search, rather than after every search.

My question here is

If I need to utilize the same PIT id every time, is it safe to expose it to the client so that the client receives the same search results every time? I want to keep the server as stateless as possible, and I want to store the PIT id somewhere, and the idea of using it directly on the server is that when the PIT id is updated (I'm thinking of generating a new PIT after an appropriate `keep_alive` time to keep the data fresh), certain clients might see inconsistent search results.